# What is the standard deviation of adult human heights for males and females?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, sex

The [wikipedia article on human height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height) reports mean height for many different countries by sex but it does not report standard deviations.

**What is the standard deviation of adult human heights within sexes?**

Obviously the size of the standard deviation would vary across countries and by other factors.  That said, I think good data on a few representative countries would be sufficient to get a reasonable sense of what it typically is and the extent to which the standard deviation varies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's probably around 7 cm for men and 6 cm for women.

[The Evolution of Adult Height in Europe](http://www.econ.upf.edu/docs/papers/downloads/1002.pdf), which is a source for some of the statistics reported on that Wikipedia page, gives averages, standard deviations, and sample sizes for both sexes across 10 european countries (and across a number of different age cohorts).

Taking their numbers for men and women born between 1966 and 1978, the average male standard deviation of height across all ten countries is 7 cm (range 6.7-7.3) and female 6.1 (range 5.6-6.4).

For a more global context, [Subramanian et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0018962) give heights with standard deviations for a much wider selection of countries, mostly "developing countries". Unfortunately for your question, they only report numbers for women. However, these  look pretty similar to the Europe numbers: the across-country average SD for women is 6.3. (with all these countries, the *range* is greater at 5.4-8.1, but 32 out of the 54 countries have SDs within the Europe range for women, i.e. 5.6-6.4)

Note: for this estimate I just ran averages across years/countries, I didn't weight the averages by sample size.

---

- [**Subramanian SVS, Özaltin EE, Finlay JEJ**. 2010. Height of nations: a socioeconomic analysis of cohort differences and patterns among women in 54 low- to middle-income countries. PLoS ONE 6: e18962–e18962.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0018962)

Comment: The first link is broken now, btw